# Option doesn't save

Tags: settings-api

I am studying wordpress settings api and tried some tutorials. I want to save the option as an array. I put some defaults for the option and it works fine, but after I save the settings, it becomes blank - string(0). How come?

My callback for the form element is this:

```
function render_checkbox($html_args){
extract($html_args);
$option_name = 'di_theme_options';
$option = get_option('di_theme_options');
printf(
    '<input type="checkbox" name="%1$s[%2$s]" id ="%2$s" value = "1" %3$s />',
    $option_name,
    $id,
    checked(1, $option[$id],false)
);
}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code but how do you know that you configured everything correctly to save the option into the DB?

Answer (score 0):

An option is a meta information saved in the database as a string. An array is a memory specific variable that has its own characteristics.

But to every problem there is a workaround:

```
$myoption = json_encode($the_array();
add_option('myoption', $myoption, '', 'yes');
```

Now to fetch it:

```
$myoption = json_decode(get_option('myoption'));
```

Voila.

When saving the option I converting to a json string format so that it fits the database table field specification and when I extract it I convert it back from json to an array.